# Find polygons that fall within a latitude/longitude combination with a N margin in degrees in MySQL/PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, gps

Normally to find polygons that compasses a certain GPS point you can use a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `polygons` WHERE ST_CONTAINS(`polygon`, POINT(-33.874087, 151.207865)));
```

However how you go with this if you would want to give the GPS point a certain **margin in degrees**? The only way i can currently think of is creating a MySQL function that does a loop that goes through every lat/long combination till it hits the margin and finally returns the polygons that it found. I'm however hoping there's a more efficient way to do this. I'm happy to do this in MySQL or PostgreSQL. Example input for finding compassing polygons:

```
latitude = 33.8275
longitude = 151.2695
latitude_span = 0.0216
longitude_span =0.0437
```

Comment: what does `margin in degrees` mean?

Comment: @Fabricator The amount in degrees that a lat/long combination can differ for finding compassing polygons. For example:

`"latitude": -33.8275
"longitude":151.2695
"latitude_span":0.0216
"longitude_span":0.0437`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Buffer` around the point to represent a circle, and check if it intersect the polygon. It appears to exist in both [psql](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html) and mysql, but I can't find any documentation for mysql.

```
select polygon
from polygons
where ST_Intersects(polygon, ST_Buffer(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(100 90)'), degrees));
```

Comment: What I'm however thinking is with the lat/long combination+margin in degrees to create a polygon and than find which polygons overlap that polygon. For example lat=50, lng = 50, degrees_lat=5, degrees_lng=10 makes the following polygon: `(47.5 55, 47.5 45, 52.5 55, 52.5 45)`. Any idea a mysql/postgre function that finds polygons that overlap an input polygon?

Comment: @bicycle, I think overlap and intersect means the same thing in this case.

Comment: @bicycle, actually, there is a [overlap](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/st_overlaps.htm) function, and it is slightly different from the [intersect](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/st_intersects.htm) one.

Comment: true but you know what i mean? To find polygons that overlap/intersect an input polygon? Searching now on Google but can't find one currently... They're mostly talking about your solution with the radius creating a circle.

Comment: @bicycle, I think the intersect and overlap function work for all geometric features.

Comment: If that is the case that would then solve my problem. Through that way i can get overlapping polygons within a square rather than a circle. I'll test it out and if it works i'll add it up as an Answer. Thanks for your help :)